# T-sql SQLcmd: Filename in a variable argument

Tags: sqlcmd

I have a sqlcmd statement

```
sqlcmd -v inz="D:\\Tcl\\scripts\\test.sql" -i D:\\test.sql -o D:\\sqlcmd.log
```

I'm getting the error: Incorrect syntax near 'D:'

Any insights? A string without the D: works fine.